How to move the exact changes made on a branch to another branch without taking previous buggy code
I need to know the standard way of working for a common scenario.
Suppose I have 2 branch

dev
qa

Now suppose the following happened:

User 1 created feature/user1 from dev and pushed to remote and merged feature/user1 to dev
User 2 also created feature/user2 from dev (so it contains User 1 code) and pushed to remote and merged feature/user2 to dev
User 1 finds a code issue and he is changing his code again in feature/user1.
Meanwhile User 2 has to move his changes to qa

Now in this situation if User 2 merges his branch feature/user2 to qa the wrong code of User1 will also go.
My questions:

How user 2 will send his commits only (not the user 1) in qa branch? Cherry picking may be a bad idea because User 2 may have made 100 commits in his branch. Range cherry picking is possible but it's a bad idea as mentioned here:
How to cherry-pick a range of commits and merge them into another branch?

As this is a very common scenario what is the best practice to follow?


Thanks in advance.

"As this is a very common scenario" Why is it common? You have a workflow where a feature branch lives on after it is merged to dev and is then merged again to qa? That is hardly a "common" way to behave — and as you can see, it's causing all kinds of issues.

I've never worked on a project of the scale this question implies, but it feels like qa should not be a single branch, if each feature has to go to qa. But maybe it's not feasible to send things feature-by-feature to qa either.

In any case, for us, once merged, if a feature needs more work, that work happens on a new branch, unless it's really breaking things.

@matt I agree best practises are not being followed here in our project which I want to put it in place.
This is I am referring as "common" because sometimes it happens that in our local machine everything works but when deployed in dev somethings may need a little modification ?  Or may be like the customer may say improve blah blah a little etc.

I found my answer myself. But I appreciate others to put their time to answer. Thank you guys !!
My Solution:
Suppose I have 3 branch:

master
qa
dev

dev contains everyone's code and it may or may not contain buggy code (In our project unless you deploy to dev you don't have connectivity to target systems. So entire testing not possible in local. I know it's crazy but this is reality for us)
What developers have to do:

Create a branch from master. Say feature1. The mistake team is doing now is creating a branch from dev which may or may not contains faulty code from others.
Put code changes in feature1 and merge it dev keeping feature1 open.
After testing I found a bug and fixes it in my feature1 branch.
Again merge feature1 to dev and do testing.
If all good merge feature1 to qa and do final testing. So although dev branch having buggy code of others, this merge will only take MY commits only and put it in higher environment branch.
If all good merge qa to master and deploy to production environment.

Any comments are welcome !!

Have user2 rebase his or her branch off the merge base between dev and qa.
Merge base colloquially means "where these branches diverged" or, more specifically, "the last common commit in these branches."
git checkout feature/user2
git rebase -i $(git merge-base --octopus dev qa)
# (This will pop open an editor, you need to remove all of the lines with
# user1's commits, then save-exit)
#
# Then once you're satisfied:
git push -f

